# Call code behind code from .ajax or PageMethods

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webforms, pagemethods

I'm trying to make a call with ajax or PageMethods but I always gets the result "undefined" back and it never run my code behind.
It it always the succes state but the data is not right.
I tried to output the data without .d but that didn't help me.

My **code behind** is:

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public static string GetCurrentTime()
    {
        return "The Current Time is: " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
```

Here is my **button**:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <input id="btnGetTime" type="button" value="Show Current Time" onclick = "ShowCurrentTime()" />
    </div>
</form>
```

I have tried with **AJAX**:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function ShowCurrentTime() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "AjaxCall.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert("fail: " + response.d);
            }
        });
    }
    function OnSuccess(response) {
        alert("success: " + response.d);
    }
</script>
```

I have also tried with **PageMethods**:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function ShowCurrentTime() {
        PageMethods.GetCurrentTime(fnsuccesscallback, fnerrorcallback);
    }
    function fnsuccesscallback(data) {
        alert("succes " + data.d);
    }
    function fnerrorcallback(result) {
        alert("fail: " + result.statusText);
    }
</script>
```

Can anyone help me with what's going wrong? :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any error in your code you are missing a reference to Jquery file.Add a Jquery file into page.

Comment: I have added jquery in my header
`
    <head runat="server">
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
`